# Loading kernel modules in Android 4.3

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Executing `lsmod` as root on my Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 gives me the error message `/proc/modules: No such file or directory`. Both devices are running Android 4.3 (but different kernel versions: 3.4.0 and 3.1.10).

My question: is it true that all prebuilt kernel versions which come with Android 4.3 do not allow loading kernel modules per default anymore, i.e., google has built them without `CONFIG_MODULES=y`?

Comment: if you are on a rooted device, than you have other then the original Google OS, than why care how is made the google build? Contact your custom rom maker instead

Comment: I haven't said anything about a custom OS, I have the original Google OS and would like to know if loading modules isn't generally supported anymore.

Comment: @jckuester Maybe the kernel was compiled without /proc support.  Is there anything under /proc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm that CONFIG_MODULES is not set in Google's 4.3 kernels. I discovered this when trying to compile additional USB modules for the Nexus 10 stock kernel.
Also, there were reports from Nexus 7 (2013) users confirming this for their kernel as well.

This is a serious regression and I have not seen any statement from Google about this.

Comment: I found my old Nexus S, running Android 4.1.2 and it is possible to load modules there. So google must have turned module support off quite recently. Actually, using `lsmod` is a good indicator to see if modules can be loaded (if you get the error `/proc/modules: No such file or directory` then it is not the case).